# Issue with Logic in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to write a multiplier based on a design. It consists of two 16-bit inputs and the a single adder is used to calculate the partial product. The LSB of one input is AND'ed with the 16 bits of the other input and the output of the AND gate is repetitively added to the previous output. The Verilog code for it is below, but I seem to be having trouble with getting the outputs to work.

```
module datapath(output reg [31:15]p_high,
                output reg [14:0]p_low,
                input [15:0]x, y,
                input clk); // reset, start, x_ce, y_ce, y_load_en, p_reset, 
               //output done);

reg [15:0]q0;
reg [15:0]q1;
reg [15:0]and_output;
reg [16:0]sum, prev_sum; 
reg d_in;
reg [3:0] count_er;

initial
 begin
      count_er <= 0;
      sum <= 17'b0;
      prev_sum <= 17'b0;
 end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
        q0 <= y;
        q1 <= x;
        and_output <= q0[count_er] & q1;
        sum <= and_output + prev_sum;    
        prev_sum <= sum;
        p_high <= sum;
        d_in <= p_high[15];
        p_low[14] <= d_in;
        p_low <= p_low >> 1;
        count_er <= count_er + 1;
 end
 endmodule
```

[image]
I created a test bench to test the circuit and the first problem I see is that, the AND operation doesn't work as I want it to. The 16-bits of the x-operand are and'ed with the LSB of the y-operand. The y-operand is shifted by one bit after every clock cycle and the final product is calculated by successively adding the partial products.

However, I am having trouble starting from the sum and prev_sum lines and their outputs are being displayed as xxxxxxxxxxxx.

Comment: *"having trouble with getting the outputs to work"*. Can you please be more specific? It's easier to debug if we have an idea of what's going wrong in the first place.

Comment: I've added a bit more content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be properly resetting all the signals you need to, or you seem to be confusing the way that nonblocking assignments work.

After initial begin:

- `sum` is 0
- `prev_sum` is 0
- `and_output` is X

After first positive edge:

- `sum` is X, because `and_output` is X, and X+0 returns X. At this point sum stays X forever, because X + something is always X.

You're creating a register for almost every signal in your design, which means that none of your signals update immediately. You need to make a distinction between the signals that you want to register, and the signals that are just combinational terms. Let the registers update with nonblocking statements on the `posedge clock`, and let the combinational terms update immediately by placing them in an `always @*` block.

I don't know the algorithm that you're trying to use, so I can't say which lines should be which, but I really doubt that you intend for it to take one clock cycle for `x/y` to propagate to `q0/q1`, another cycle for `q` to propagate to `and_output`, and yet another clock cycle to propogate from `and_output` to sum.

---

Comments on updated code:

- Combinational blocks should use blocking assignments, not nonblocking assignments. Use `=` instead of `<=` inside the always @* block.
- `sum <= and_output + sum;` looks wrong, It should be `sum = and_output + p_high[31:16]` according to your picture.
- You're assigning p_low[14] twice here. Make the second statement explicitly set bits [13:0] only:

  ```
  p_low[14]   <= d_in;
  p_low[13:0] <= p_low >> 1;
  ```

Comment: I've updated the code, but not sure if the comments will be able to hold the modified code. I've also pasted the link to the circuit that I'm trying to implement. Updated code: http://pastebin.com/NSaayfHG , Design: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/793037/2013-03-22_2236.png

Comment: @GamingX - I edited in some additional comments on your new code, hopefully that will get you started. If you still have problems, try tracing the signals in your simulator to see where the problems lie.

Comment: I don't think the changes you made were saved. It probably creates a new link once you make the changes.

Comment: I meant I edited my post above, I didn't do anything on the pastebin. See the last few bullets of my answer post above. @GamingX

Comment: I made all the changes that you've suggested, but without any luck. I'm still starting out with it, so not exactly sure of the debugging steps

Comment: You just need to pull up all your relevant signals in the waveform generator, start from time=0, and then look at the signal state after each clock cycle and compare it to your expected values by looking at your schematic diagram. If **after** doing this you still can't figure out what's going on, then feel free to update your original post with the most recent code that you are using and a clear description of what's not behaving the way you expect. Best of luck @GamingX

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim. I got it working. It seems that the ANDing operation does not work as I desired when ANDing a single bit. So I had to first determine the last bit of the multiplicand (y-operand) and depending on whether it was a 1 or a zero, I had to set it as 16'b1111111111111111 or 16'b0000000000000000 respectively and then perform the AND operation

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing blocking and nonblocking assignments in the same sequential `always` block, which can cause unexpected results:

```
d_in <= p_high[15];
p_low[14] = d_in;
```

Comment: I've modified it but with no positive results, but thanks for pointing it out.